# what is the trust region algorithm in optimization?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I see some books that say the trust region work with contour's line .but i can't understand

how choose the point with contour's line and sort them?

thank you if answer me.

Comment: I don't see exactly what you mean. The trust region method is based on optimizing over the search direction for an approximation of the cost function (e.g. quadratic) where the norm of the search direction is bounded (by a _trust region_).

Comment: but how choose the trust region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nocedal/Wright propose in Numerical Optimization (1999) on p.68 the following pseudo-code for iteratively setting the size of the trust-region:

> Algorithm 4.1 (Trust Region).
>   Given $\bar\Delta > 0, \Delta_0 \in (0,\bar{\Delta})$, and $\eta \in [0, \frac{1}{4})$: 
>   **for** $k=0,1,2,...$ 
>   $\qquad$ Obtain $p_k$ by approximately solving the [the optimization problem];
>   $\qquad$ Evaluate $\rho_k = \frac{f(x_k)-f(x_k + p_k)}{m_k(0)-m_k(p_k)}$;
>   $\qquad$ **if** $\rho_k < \frac{1}{4}$
>   $\qquad\qquad \Delta_{k+1} = \frac{1}{4}\lVert p_k \rVert$
>   $\qquad$ **else**
>   $\qquad\qquad$ **if** $\rho_k > \frac{3}{4}$ and $\lVert p_k \rVert = \Delta_k$
>   $\qquad\qquad\qquad \Delta_{k+1} = \min(2\Delta_k, \bar{\Delta})$
>   $\qquad\qquad$ **else**
>   $\qquad\qquad\qquad \Delta_{k+1} = \Delta_k;$
>   $\qquad$ **if** $\rho_k > \eta$
>   $\qquad\qquad x_{k+1} = x_k + p_k$
>   $\qquad$ **else** 
>   $\qquad\qquad x_{k+1} = x_k;$
>   **end(for).**

Where $p_k$ is the search direction, $\bar{\Delta}$ is the trust region's upper bound, $\Delta_0$ is the starting size of the trust region, $f$ is the cost function and $m_k$ its quadratic approximation at $x_k$:

> $$m_k(p) = f(x_k) + ((\nabla f)(x_k))^T p + \frac{1}{2}p^T B_k p,$$

$B_k$ being the Hessian.

The upper bound $\bar{\Delta}$ must be chosen according to your problem. This means that you have to have a rough idea of where the minimum might reside.

Comment: about $\bar{\Delta}$ how i find the region that minimum might reside ?by guess

Comment: Say, you're looking for a flight route between two airports that minimizes the distance under consideration of some bad weather reports whilst the nominal range of your airliner is 20k miles. Then I wouldn't choose $\bar{\Delta} = 10^6$ miles.

Comment: excuse me .can you guide me about merit function ?

Comment: What do you need to know?

Comment: when we use merit function in optimization & why uses this function?

Comment: Do you mind posting this question publicly? Otherwise feel free to send me an [email](http://www.blaetterundsterne.org).

Comment: I post this question publicly

Comment: excuse me can you give me the refrence of this algorithm?

Comment: Nocedal/Wright *Numerical Optimization* (1999) p.68